# Hibernate with JSON (no DB table)

Tags: json, oracle, hibernate

I am stuck with a peculiar scenario on JSON / Hibernate. Here goes -

I have an existing application with Oracle DB and Hibernate / JPA. Now, I need to use JSON data rather than DB table data for some of the domain / entity classes while keeping the hibernate framework intact. This is required because I still need to use the existing hibernate / Oracle interaction for the rest of the domain classes. Once I replace the DB table data with JSON, those DB tables will no longer be available to the application. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
Thanks Vlad for you input. I went through the article. But I think my scenario is a little different. Let's say I have two entities - Country and City which are currently mapped to the DB tables COUNTRY and CITY respectively. City has a Country. Now, I want to remove the DB table COUNTRY and instead provide JSON data to the application. How can I handle that while still enjoying Hibernate services like caching etc even for Country.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project which allows you to persist JSON properties as:

- List
- Map
- JsonNode
- POJOs

For a detailed example, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/).